# How do I do a video like this?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXW1dh2XH9Y Basically I want to make a video with a moving picture that moves with a person in a video's head.

Comment: This isn't 3d work... go get After Effects.

Comment: @AlexSafayan Actually, this can be done in the compositor, VSE, or movie clip editor.

Comment: @ShadyPuck Yes, I know, but why would you render that if you can just use a video editing software?

Comment: K now how do I do it?

Comment: @AlexSafayan He's asking how to. Blender's free. Blender has more possibilities.

Comment: The video you linked is so poorly made... You can do so much better with motion tracking, then using that tracking information to control the image being overlaid on top.